# MySQL Update on Huge Table

Tags: mysql, locking, temp-tables

I want to update a table with 90 million records.

For example:

```
UPDATE huge_table set field3 = CONCAT_WS(' ', field1, field2)
```

The update locks the table for a while and I want to minimize the amount of time locked.

Should I populate a temp table to store the values, then assign them from the temp table?  Or should I try to update in batches of 1000? Perhaps a combination of both.

Comment: Still not sure what solution to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would run the update in batches.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a load like that in a different environment and re-point the table instead to the fresh data set.

Answer (score 0):

None of both. You need the update to be as fast as possible. If you create a temporary table then you will be adding 90 million inserts and deletes.

Consider table partitioning. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-overview.html.